# Is there any way to build a React App and leave env variables that can be dynamically populated?

Tags: reactjs, django, build

I have a react app that is served via Django. I have multiple environments: staging and prod. These environments have different URLs that the API is exposed from.

On building the React app I'm passing variable that tells the build which URL to use, but this gets to be a mess with the multiple environments and git. I end up having a git history filled with builds from other environemnts. These builds get passed to other branches when PRs are merged, then they create conflicts, etc.

I want to have a single React build that will be able to tell which environment it is and update the API url accordingly: after being built!

Is that possible?

Comment: How are you building the app?

Comment: Building it via 'npm run build' locally. Then I relocate the build to the backend, commit the changes, and push it to the heroku app (prod or staging depending on environment)

Comment: Yes, but what build system are we taking about? Cra? Webpack? Something else?

Comment: I'm using Webpack

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately this is not possible with a React application. There are methods that can tell which environment it is and populate the environment variables but that is BEFORE npm run build is ran. If you want a solution that involves that, please revise your question. Reference:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

```
The environment variables are embedded during the build time. Since Create React App produces a static HTML/CSS/JS bundle, it can’t possibly read them at runtime.
```