# How to create single bundle for different environments in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, npm

We have a ReactJS application that has been deployed to four different environments: dev, qa, sbx, and prod. During the build process, environment-specific variables are embedded into the application using an .env file. In the package.json file, we have configured these environment-specific variables so that they are set accordingly for each environment. In package.json we have

```
"scripts": {    
    "build:dev": "env-cmd -f ./dev.env react-scripts build",
    "build:qa": "env-cmd -f ./qa.env react-scripts build",
    "build:sbx": "env-cmd -f ./sbx.env react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f ./prod.env react-scripts build"  
}
```

and then for each environment we create bundle using commands

```
npm run build:dev
npm run build:qa
npm run build:sbx
npm run build:prod
```

The deployment process then simply copies the bundle to each environment.

Although all four bundles were created from the same git branch and they differ in environment variable values, they are still technically different bundles. My goal is to create one single bundle - a "golden artifact" - and deploy it to four different environments, while varying the variable values according to each environment.

I want to know if this is even possible with ReactJS.  If so, what steps should I take?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: It is not possible, the environment variables are intrinsically linked to the build files and it's designed to not allow dynamic variables after it's built.

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You can see my answer that explains it here: [Is there any way to build a React App and leave env variables that can be dynamically populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72839292/is-there-any-way-to-build-a-react-app-and-leave-env-variables-that-can-be-dynami/76038888#76038888).